# integer validation gives infinite loop

Tags: c, validation, char, scanf

The user needs to type an integer, then type enter.  If it gets validated then it should return the integer,  if not validated the user should get an error message.

When I try to validate input through `getInt()` function, I get an infinite loop when I type 1 or more chars. When I type `abc`, I get an infinite loop of error messages, while entering `1a` gets the correct validation (1 single error message). I followed the directions of this flowchart:

[image: getInt() flowchart]

#### Code

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  void clrKyb(void){
    char input;
    do {
      scanf("%c",&input);
    } while(input !='\n');
  }

  int getInt(void){
    char NL= 'x' ;
    int value ;

    while(NL!='\n'){

      scanf("%d%c",&value,&NL);

      if(NL!='\n') {

       void clrKyb(void);
       printf("Invalid integer, please try again:");

      }

    }   
    return value ;
  }


  int main(void) {
    int iVal;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    iVal = getInt();
    printf("You entered: %d\n", iVal);

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: In `getInt`, `void clrKyb(void);` should just be `clrKyb();`, since you are wanting to use the `clrKyb` you have already defined.

Comment: Note that in `clrKyB()` (and `getInt()`), you need to check the return value from `scanf()`.  If it returns EOF, then no amount of retrying etc is going to stop an infinite loop.  (As cxw notes, in `getInt()` at the moment, you (re)declare `clrKyB()` and don't call it — that's also a problem.)

Comment: Thank you  @cxw and Jonathan Leffler . Changing void clrKyb(void) to clrKyb() fixed my problem . I did not  know something like this could affect an infinite loop , i thought i had to add something inside scanf function .Btw how can i mark this answer solved by a comment by a comment (I am new here) .

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler

Comment: @elvisi27: there isn't a formal way to accept an answer until there is an answer rather than a comment.  I'll create an answer from the two operative comments.  Since it is a combined effort, I'll make it 'CW' (community wiki) which means that neither cxw nor I will get any points out of it, but you'll be able to accept it (you get your bonus), and the question will be visibly 'completed'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments:

[cxw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877364/cxw) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289857/integer-validation-gives-infinite-loop?noredirect=1#comment67837881_40289857):

- In `getInt`, `void clrKyb(void);` should just be `clrKyb();`, since you are wanting to use the `clrKyb` you have already defined.

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289857/integer-validation-gives-infinite-loop?noredirect=1#comment67837983_40289857):

- Note that in `clrKyB()` (and `getInt()`), you need to check the return value from `scanf()`. If it returns EOF, then no amount of retrying etc is going to stop an infinite loop. (As [cxw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877364/cxw) notes, in `getInt()` at the moment, you (re)declare `clrKyB()` and don't call it — that's also a problem.)